# Error button is not defined?

Tags: python, nameerror

This is my code:

```py
import sys
from tkinter import *


def next_screen(names):
    for widget in names:
        widget.place_forget()   

def forget_page1():
    widgets = [mLabel1, button]
    next_screen(widgets)

mGui = Tk ()

mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")
mLabel1 = Label (text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",
                 fg = "blue",bg = "white")
mLabel1.place (x= 150,y = 200)

button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1 ())
button.place(x = 275,y = 230)

mGui.mainloop()
```

It tells me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Python33\Projects\MyMathDictionary.py", line 24, in <module>
    button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1 (mLabel,button)) NameError: name 'button' is not defined
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: You do realise your exception and your code show different code for the same line right? :)

Comment: The arguments of `forgetpage()` in your code sample are different from the error message. Referring to `button` in the same line you're defining it isn't going to work, of course.

Comment: don't `import *`, you'll clutter up your namespace uselessly

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code:

```
button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1 ())
```

To this:

```
button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1)
```

Your problem was that you were calling `forget_page1` before the window loaded.

Also, as the comments have already said, your error is different than your code.  But, I'll go over that quickly too just in case.  If you want to send arguments to a button's command function, you need to use a `lambda`:

```
button = Button(command = lambda: func(arg1, arg2))
```

Comment: Ok but why lambdas??? can't i use it with forget_page(x)... and the  error message ... i copied it afterward and chenged the code sorry for that ...

Comment: @ChaudryShahidIqbal - You have to use a `lambda` if you plan to send arguments to your function.  Otherwise, when Python reads through your script and reaches that point, it will call your function.  `lambda` is basically an inline function.  In other words, its a function calling a function to keep that function from being called on startup.